# Compile-time check for existence of a template specialization of a function using C++20 requires expression

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-specialization

I am developing a sort of event system where the event listeners are determined at compile-time. To achieve this, I need a function which can tell me whether the parameter `class T` implements a specific specialization of the `OnEvent()` function.

My current attempt uses a C++20 `requires` expression:

```
template<class T>
class ScriptComponent
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Script, T>, "T must derive from Script!");

private:
    T m_ScriptInstance;

public:
    // Should return true if t.OnEvent<E>(e) can compile, false otherwise.
    template<typename E>
    constexpr static bool ImplementsEventFunction()
    {
        constexpr bool isImplemented = requires(const T& t, const E& e)
        {
            t.OnEvent<E>(e);
        };
        return isImplemented;
    }
};
```

Example of a class which can listen to events:

```
class SomeScript : public Script
{
public:
    // delete any non-specialized templates
    template<typename E>
    void OnEvent(const E&) = delete;

    // the template specialization I want to check for
    template<>
    void OnEvent<SomeEvent>(const SomeEvent& e)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
};
```

Usage of `ImplementsEventFunction()` :

```
// should return true (there is a OnEvent() specialization for SomeEvent)
constexpr bool a = ScriptComponent<SomeScript>ImplementsEventFunction<SomeEvent>();
// should return false (there is no OnEvent() specialization for SomeOtherEvent)
constexpr bool b = ScriptComponent<SomeScript>ImplementsEventFunction<SomeOtherEvent>();
```

`ImplementsEventFunction()` always returns false no matter what the template parameters are. Obviously, I seem to be using the requires expression wrong, but I cannot find my mistake.

Comment: Why do you *need* `OnEvent` to explicitly be a template? Why can't a user implement `OnEvent` as a non-template function that takes a particular `E`?

Comment: @NicolBolas You're completely right... I don't know why I was stuck on using templates when function overloading was obviously the way to go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to *require* `OnEvent` to be implemented as a template. This feels like being overly-controlling of the user's code. Concepts are not for telling the user how exactly to implement something. You are going to call an interface in a certain way, and users should implement their code such that that call syntax is valid.

And your code ought to be using `t.OnEvent(e)`. There is no reason why your code needs to specify the template argument explicitly at the call site. Users should be able to implement `OnEvent` for some particular `E` as a non-template function (or multiple non-template overloads), or as a template function with template argument deduction taking care of the template parameter.

As such, the proper concept would be:

```
template<typename T, typename E>
concept has_event_for = requires(T t, E e)
{
  t.OnEvent(e);
};

class SomeScript : public Script
{
public:
  void OnEvent(const SomeEvent& e)
  {
      // do stuff
  }

  //No need to delete anything or use templates.
};
```

Don't treat concepts like you would base classes, where you explicitly spell out the exact parameters which derived class interfaces must exactly follow.

---

If however you absolutely must do this, you have to use the `template` keyword at the call site:

```
template<typename T, typename E>
concept has_event_for = requires(T t, E e)
{
  t.template OnEvent<E>(e);
};
```

This is yet another reason not to do it this way.